# How to call webservice using ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, android, threadpoolexecutor

I would like to call the webservice using **ThreadPoolExecutor** in android application instead of **AsyncTask**. Webservice call should be parallel and queues. How to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to create ThreadPoolExecutor. The easiest is create use predefined executors in [Executors](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). After add a wrapper around it to execute your queries.

In general it is a complicated task, because you should correct manage tasks (cancel, re-query,...).

See simple example below

```
public class RequestExecutor {

    private static final int POOL_SIZE = 2;

    private final ExecutorService mExecutorService;
    private final Handler mUiHandler;

    public RequestExecutor(Handler uiHandler) {
        mExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE);
        mUiHandler = uiHandler;
    }

    public <E> void execute(final IRequest<E> request, final ResultListener<E> listener) {
        // manage future entry later, if need
        Future future = mExecutorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request requestHttp = new Request.Builder().url(request.getUrl()).build();

                try {
                    Response response = client.newCall(requestHttp).execute();
                    String responseString = response.body().string();
                    E resp = request.parse(responseString);
                    notifySuccess(listener, resp);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    notifyFailure(listener, e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void notifyFailure(final ResultListener<?> listener, Throwable e) {
        // handle exceptions here
        final int errorCode = 401;
        mUiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listener.onError(errorCode);
            }
        });
    }

    protected <E> void notifySuccess(final ResultListener<E> listener, final E resp) {
        mUiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listener.onSuccess(resp);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface IRequest<E> {
        String getUrl();

        E parse(String resp);
    }

    public interface ResultListener<E> {
        void onSuccess(E result);

        void onError(int errorCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: POOL_SIZE should be handled by system. Is it possible?

Comment: @RamkiAnba in this case you can use java.util.concurrent.Executors#newCachedThreadPool()

Answer (score 1):

1. First create an instance of ThreadPoolExecutor:

   `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(<number of threads you needs inside pool>);`
2. Then add your api calls inside Runnable method:

   executor.execute(new Runnable() 
   {

   ```
       @Override
       public void run() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }
   });
   ```

For More Detail: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: Is it possible to handle the pool size by system?

Comment: Yup...pool size will be handled by system. Once the pool gets full the ExecutorService will start caching the new Runnables and execute them as soon as one of already running thread finished.

Comment: have the system desired that number of threads needs inside pool?

Comment: yup...for further detail...i already provided the link go ahead and look at the android documentation.